# How to read Torch Tensor from C

Tags: c, lua, neural-network, luajit, torch

I have to train a convolutional neural network using the Torch framework and then write the same network in C. 
To do so, I have to read somehow the learned parameters of the net from my C program, but I can't find a way to convert or write to a file the Torch Tensors to make them readable in C. 
Ideally, I want to convert the Tensors into arrays of double in C.

Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't find a way to convert or write to a file the Torch Tensors to make them readable in C. Ideally, I want to convert the Tensors into arrays of double in C.

The most basic (and direct) way is to directly `fread` in C the data you have previously written into a binary file. In such a case you would typically concatenate the weights and biases (if any) for each layer.

On the Lua/Torch side you can use the [File](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/file.md) utilities to literally `fwrite` each tensor data. For example here is a basic function that does that:

```
local fwrite = function(tensor, file)
  if not tensor then return false end
  local n = tensor:nElement()
  local s = tensor:storage()
  return assert(file:writeDouble(s) == n)
end
```

For example if `m` refers to a `torch/nn` module containing weights you would use it as follow:

```
local file = torch.DiskFile("net.bin", "w"):binary()
fwrite(m.weight, file)
fwrite(m.bias, file)
```

Of course you need to write your own logic to make sure you `fwrite` and concatenate all the weights from all your layers. On the C side, in addition to `net.bin`, you also need to know the structure of your network (nb. layers, parameters like kernel size, etc) to know how many block of `double`-s to `fread`.

As an example (in Lua) you can have a look at [overfeat-torch](https://github.com/jhjin/overfeat-torch) (non official project) that illustrates how to read such a plain binary file: see the [ParamBank](https://github.com/jhjin/overfeat-torch/blob/09e10a6818ee8e079d923c63a9afc55d86ac4515/run.lua#L83-L100) tool.

Keep in mind that a robust solution would consist in using a proper binary serialization format like [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/) or [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) that would make this export/import process clean and portable.

--

Here is a toy example:

```
-- EXPORT
require 'nn'

local fwrite = function(tensor, file)
  if not tensor then return false end
  local n = tensor:nElement()
  local s = tensor:storage()
  return assert(file:writeDouble(s) == n)
end

local m = nn.Linear(2, 2)

print(m.weight)
print(m.bias)

local file = torch.DiskFile("net.bin", "w"):binary()
fwrite(m.weight, file)
fwrite(m.bias, file)
```

Then in C:

```
/* IMPORT */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int
main(void)
{
  const int N = 2; /* nb. neurons */

  double *w = malloc(N*N*sizeof(*w)); /* weights */
  double *b = malloc(N*sizeof(*w));   /* biases */

  FILE *f = fopen("net.bin", "rb");
  assert(fread(w, sizeof(*w), N*N, f) == N*N);
  assert(fread(b, sizeof(*w), N, f) == N);
  fclose(f);

  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
      printf("w[%d,%d] = %f\n", i, j, w[N*i+j]);

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
      printf("b[%d] = %f\n", i, b[i]);

  free(w);
  free(b);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I already tried to write to a file from Lua and then read from C using fread as you suggested, but I only obtained garbage! I tried again today with floats instead of doubles and it works :D Thank you again!

Comment: Just added a toy example to illustrate the process.