# Is there a common format for neural networks

Tags: neural-network, theano, deep-learning, caffe, torch

Different teams use different libraries to train and run neural networks (caffe, torch, theano...). This makes sharing difficult: each library has its own format to store networks and you have to install a new library each time you want to test other teams' work.

I am looking for solutions to make this less tedious:
- Is there a preferred (shared?) format to store neural networks?
- Is there a service or library that can help handle different types of networks / or transform one type into another?

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is there a preferred (shared?) format to store neural networks?

Each library / framework has its own serialization, e.g. Caffe uses [Protocol Buffers](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/net_layer_blob.html#model-format), Torch has a [built-in serialization scheme](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/840e7312e51e3dd6e28583d4020bfe134eadb9cf/doc/serialization.md) and Theano objects can be [serialized with pickle](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/loading_and_saving.html).

In some cases like [OverFeat](https://github.com/sermanet/OverFeat) or [darknet](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet) the weights and biases are stored on-disk in binary format via plain `fwrite`-s of the corresponding `float`(or `double`) contiguous arrays (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30058467/1688185) for more details). Note that this does not cover the architecture of the network / model which has to be known or represented separately (like [declared explicitly at load time](https://github.com/jhjin/overfeat-torch/blob/17e308dcd093b16fa39dedc452cac72ce85a6e8b/run.lua#L37-L56)).

Also: a library like [libccv](http://libccv.org/) stores the structure and the weights in a [SQLite database](https://github.com/deltheil/loadccv/blob/1c965183163b95a100113491c8b305b55df267cb/init.lua#L103-L128).

> Is there a service or library that can help handle different types of networks / or transform one type into another?

I don't think there is a single (meta) library that claims to do so. But it exists distinct projects that provide convenient converters.

Some examples (non exhaustive):

- Caffe -> Torch: https://github.com/szagoruyko/loadcaffe
- Torch -> Caffe: https://github.com/facebook/fb-caffe-exts
- Caffe -> TensorFlow: https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow

--

**UPDATE** (2017-09): two noticeable initiatives are:

(1) the [ONNX](https://github.com/onnx) format (a.k.a. Open Neural Network Exchange):

> [...] a standard for representing deep learning models that enables models to be transferred between frameworks

*See these [blog](https://research.fb.com/facebook-and-microsoft-introduce-new-open-ecosystem-for-interchangeable-ai-frameworks/) [posts](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/blog/2017/09/microsoft-facebook-create-open-ecosystem-ai-model-interoperability/).*

(2) the [CoreML](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/coremlspecification/) format introduced by Apple:

> [...] a public file format (`.mlmodel`) for a broad set of ML methods [...] Models in this format can be directly integrated into apps through Xcode.

Comment: Another recent initiative is the [Neural Network Exchange Format](https://www.khronos.org/nnef/) by the Khronos Group.

Answer (score 9):

## ONNX (Open Neural Network Exchange)

**ONNX** is an open-source AI ecosystem that provides a **common format for neural networks**.

- It helps **converting** a deep learning model to another.

  Generally, model conversion takes weeks/months without **ONNX**:
  [image]

  **ONNX** offers simpler and faster conversion process:
  [image]

  <sub>For all supported conversions, see [here](https://onnx.ai/supported-tools).</sub>
- It makes **deployment** easier, models stored in a much preferable way:
  [image]
  In the above image, ONNX acts as a **data ingestion layer**, transforms each input model to the same format. Otherwise, all models would be like a bunch of puzzle pieces that do not fit each other.

---

#### How to Use ONNX - Keras Conversion Example

[image]

Let's say you have your **Keras** model and you want to transform it to **ONNX**:

```
model = load_model("keras_model.hdf5")  # h5 is also OK!

onnx_model = keras2onnx.convert_keras(model, model.name)

onnx_model_file = 'output_model.onnx'
onnx.save_model(onnx_model, onnx_model_file)
```

Then load & run saved model :

```
onnx_model = onnx.load_model('output_model.onnx')

content = onnx_model.SerializeToString()
sess = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(content)
x = x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]
feed = dict([(input.name, x[n]) for n, input in enumerate(sess.get_inputs())])

# Do inference
pred_onnx = sess.run(None, feed)
```

This example uses [keras2onnx](https://github.com/onnx/keras-onnx) to **convert** the **Keras** model and [onnxruntime](https://pypi.org/project/onnxruntime/) to do **inference**.

**Note:** There are also lots of pre-trained models in the ONNX format. Check [this](https://github.com/onnx/models) out!

---

<sub>References:</sub>

<sub><sub>1. https://towardsdatascience.com/onnx-made-easy-957e60d16e94</sub></sub>
 
<sub><sub>2. https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2019/08/portability-deep-learning-frameworks-onnx/</sub></sub>
 
<sub><sub>3. http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2018/presentation/s8818-onnx-interoperable-deep-learning-presented-by-facebook.pdf</sub></sub>
 
<sub><sub>4. https://devblogs.nvidia.com/tensorrt-3-faster-tensorflow-inference/</sub></sub>